# Python socket HTTP 1.1 CONNECT request without a valid response

Tags: python, html, request, response, http-1.1

Well, I just want to make the following simple program that tries to create an https tunel with www.google.com at port 443. I first tried the following code:

```
import socket

def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("www.google.com", 80))
    request = "CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1\n\n"
    s.send(request.encode())
    print(s.recv(4096).decode())

main()
```

The result of that was the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Referrer-Policy: no-referrer

Content-Length: 1592

Date: Wed, 16 Aug 2017 07:56:14 GMT

Connection: close



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 405 (Method Not Allowed)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>405.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The request method <code>CONNECT</code> is inappropriate for the URL <code>/</code>.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

That means that the server does not allow this request to be executed. So I thought that the problem was the port number. So I changed it to 443(which is the port for https connection). The code is that:

```
def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("www.google.com", 443))
    request = "CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1\n\n"
    s.send(request.encode())
    print(s.recv(4096).decode())

main()
```

But it does not print out a valid respnse as it should have done. It gives me an empty response.
The question to that is: "Why is that happening? How can I make it work properly?"
Note: I don't want to use built-in urllib or urllib2 libraries. I want to do that with sockets.

Comment: Change request to this: ` request = "GET www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"`

Answer (score 6):

## HTTP

In your original connection to port 80 you are just using wrong `Host`:

```
import socket


def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('google.com', 80))
    request = b'CONNECT google.com HTTP/1.1\n\n'
    s.send(request)
    print(s.recv(4096).decode())

main()
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
```

Or use `GET` method right away:

```
request = b'GET http://google.com HTTP/1.1\n\n'
```

Response is the same as to HTTPS request, `google.com` host doesn't work for some reason.

## HTTPS

You should wrap your socket in ssl tunnel (not sure if correct term) in order to connect using HTTPS, and `GET` method is ready to use right after connection:

```
import socket
import ssl


def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s = ssl.wrap_socket(s)
    s.connect(('google.com', 443))
    request = b'GET google.com HTTP/1.1\n\n'
    s.send(request)
    print(s.recv(4096).decode())

main()
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Location: https://www.google.ru/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=WwCUWc66L6qB3APs7ZPABA
Content-Length: 259
Date: Wed, 16 Aug 2017 08:20:43 GMT
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,35"

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.ru/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=WwCUWc66L6qB3APs7ZPABA">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. Secondly, is it sure that the code you wrote without wraping is working? Cause I interpreted that but nothing changed

Comment: Yes, I'm getting "200 connection established" response. I'm using Python 3.6, maybe that's the issue?

Comment: I use Python 6.2 and I copy-paste the first http code. Unfortunately it doesn't do anything! It returns a 405 Status Code[Method not allowed]

Comment: 6.2? Did you try sending get request?

Comment: The GET request works properly. The problem occurs in CONNECT request

Comment: To help you understand what I am talking about, I am trying to make a simple proxy server in which I connect my browser.